# Binding an attached property to an item in ItemsControl with custom panel problem

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

I can't get the following XAML to work as I want. All bindings work because get no errors from the bindings. But I don't get the expected result from the binding on the **RatioShape** rectangle. The problem is that the attached property **wpflib:RatioPanel.Ratio** always returns its default value, not the databound value.

So I'm thinking that the attached property on **RatioShape** is set in the wrong "context". How do bind to the attached property so that **wpflib:RatioPanel** gets the bound value?

```
<wpflib:RatioContentPresenter2 RatioMaxValue="{Binding Path=RatioMaxValue}">
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" wpflib:RatioContentPresenter2.RatioOffset="{Binding Path=RatioOffset}" wpflib:RatioContentPresenter2.RatioValue="{Binding Path=RatioValue}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <wpflib:RatioPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Name="RatioShape" wpflib:RatioPanel.Ratio="{Binding Path=Value}" Fill="{Binding Path=Brush}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <Binding  Path="RatioItems" Mode="OneWay" />
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    </ItemsControl>
</wpflib:RatioContentPresenter2>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The children of the RatioPanel will be instances of ContentPresenter, assuming the items are not UIElements. The ContentPresenter will display the DataTemplate you have defined in ItemTemplate.

Normally, panels work directly with their children. You are setting your attached property on the a child of the ContentPresenter, which is a child of your panel. I believe you should be setting this on the ContentPresenter directly. So something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="wpflib:RatioPanel.Ratio" Value="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle x:Name="RatioShape" Fill="{Binding Path=Brush}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: why the hell attached properties have to be set differently? It's confusing asf. Damn WPF.

Comment: 12 years later, still a useful answer. ChatGPT just can't beat some classic answers.